# SharePoint Online Modern Site- Key filter control/webpart

Tags: navigation, sharepoint-online, spfx

I want to add Key filter webpart at left side of list for taxonomy column filter. But in modern site it is not coming. Can you please help me to do it or is there any alternative for the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use column formatting and list view filters to achieve some level of taxonomy column filtering. While this won't be exactly the same as the Key Filter web part, you can create custom views for your list that filter based on your taxonomy column.